# Jackson @Deserializer doesn't work

Tags: jackson, deserialization

This is a duplicated question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021098/springmvc-jsondeserialize-doesnt-work)

**POJO**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pet")
public class Pet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long petId;

    private String petName;

    private Date birthday;

    @JsonSerialize(using = Serializer.class)
    public Date getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    @JsonDeserialize(using = Deserializer.class)
    public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public Long getPetId() {
        return petId;
    }

    public void setPetId(Long petId) {
        this.petId = petId;
    }

    public String getPetName() {
        return petName;
    }

    public void setPetName(String petName) {
        this.petName = petName;
    }
}
```

**Serializer**

```
public class Serializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        System.out.println("Serializer");
    }
}
```

**Deserializer**

```
public class Deserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {
    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        System.out.println("Deserializer works.");
        return new Date();
    }
}
```

Maven Dependency

```
<dependency> 
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency> 
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency> 
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

**update: controller code**

```
@Transactional
@Controller
public class Demo {

    @Resource
    private Dao dao;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String tester(Pet pet){
        dao.saveOrUpdate(pet);
        return "success";
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/test2")
    public List<Pet> tester2(){
        List<Pet> pets = dao.query(Pet.class);
        return pets;
    }
}
```

however only **Serializer** will be invoked everytime, **Deserializer** doesn't take any effect, I can't see where is wrong, could anybody help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to use both above the getter, move the one from setter to getter and try, if that does not works, use above the property

Comment: Try to set the annotation above the class definition and verify that the Date object is always the same.

Comment: @Koitoer still the same, no matter where i put the annotation, only Serializer does work.

Comment: @Jens actually if put above class definition, there will be exception occurs, because you see my Serializer type is Date rather than a PoJo class

Comment: @Z.Neeson is the date in Serializer , Deserializer and pet allways the same? I guess `java.util.date`?

Comment: @Jens yes you're right, date is java.util.date, but what do you mean by 'always the same'?

Comment: @Z.Neeson has you imported in class Deserializer also java.util.Date? Not java.sql.Date what sometimes happend.

Comment: @Jens please see my updated code for controller

Comment: @Jens Double checked again, they are the same, both java.util.date

Comment: @Jens I tried on petName property which is a String object also, still the same, only Serializer works, and this project is a blank project for Jackson only, without any other unnecessary stuffs.

Comment: Can you try this syntax: (@JsonDeserialize(as=Date.class, using=Deserializer.class)) ?

Comment: @Jens tried, but still same, nothing be changed

Comment: @Jens when I create a new Pet object, Deserializer will be invoked right?

Comment: I think it is called when you comes with a string and convert it to a date.

Comment: @Jens just now I tested created a Pet trough a page form, but still get the same problem, I searched lots of example, I don't see any difference with mine, quite wired, really don't understand why